# solving autonomous ODE

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve a autonomous ODE system by using scipy ode.
The code has no syntax mistake but it cannot give the correct answer. 
It gives,

```
/Users/daoyuan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:741: 
UserWarning: vode: Illegal input detected. (See printed message. 
                                               'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
```

Here is my code

```
from numpy import*

from scipy.integrate import  ode

def autonomous_function(y,t):
    y1=y[0]
    y2=y[1]
    dy1=y1**2*y2-4*y1+1
    dy2=3*y1-y1**2*y2
    return [y1,y2]

t0=0
y10=0
y20=0
t_final=1
dt=1/10

solver=ode(autonomous_function)
solver.set_integrator('vode')
solver.set_initial_value([y10,y20],t0)

y_result=[]
t_output=[]

y_result.append([y10,y20])
t_output.append(t0)

while solver.successful() and solver.t<t_final:
    solver.integrate(solver.t+dt)

    y_result.append(solver.y)
    t_output.append(t_output)

y_result=array(y_result)
t_output=array(t_output)

y_result
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but `autonomous_function` doesn't seem to do anything except return the `y` it started with.  It doesn't do anything with `dy`

Comment: You've also got a problem that dt=0 (at least in python 2.7).

Comment: and the `y` being sent to `autonomous_function` is a float, but it's expecting a list.

Comment: I think the fact that dt=0 is causing the integration to skip doing anything.  This is causing other errors to be hidden from you.

Comment: doing      `from numpy import*`      is not recommended. you should instead do `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an obvious mistake in your code is the fact that you are integrating `y` instead of `dy`.

By fixing some other minor mistakes, the final code should be:

```
import numpy as np 
from RKF import rkf

def autonomous_function(t,y):
    y1=y[0]
    y2=y[1]
    dy1=y1**2 *y2-4*y1+1
    dy2=3*y1-y1**2 *y2
    return np.array([dy1,dy2])

t0=0
t_final=1
y0=[0,0]

t,u=rkf(f=autonomous_function, a=t0,b=t_final,x0=y0).solve()

y1,y2=u.T

print("t shape:",t.shape,"\ny1 shape:", y1.shape,"\ny2 shape:",y2.shape)
```

Output:

```
  Execution time: 0.0023386 seconds
  Number of data points: 32
  t shape: (32,)
  y1 shape: (32,)
  y2 shape: (32,)
```